# Dynamic size slider control in javaFx

Tags: java, video, slider, javafx

We are coding a Video Editor in JavaFx.We use cutin and cutout point on this video to extract a clip. For long videos we need a dynamic slider which can zoom or elongate if videos are four hours or longer so that a user can fine edit at minute points.I tried zooming in JavaFx but Zoom makes slider looks too bad.Is there any similar thing which you guys have seen or implemented ? Or any ideas about how to implement it?

Currently my slider is in AnchorPane and set its start and stop time according to movie-length. Fine-editing a long movie(of duration 10 hours or more) becomes difficult with a steady slider.

Answer (score 0):

The idea that comes to my mind is that you could rescale (change pixel width) the slider according to "Zoom Level". Thereby JavaFX should still display it correctly. Though that might be a bit of a clumsy solution.

Comment: Thanks NexusTeddy , I have tried that and it doesn't seem to be very nice solution.

Comment: Couldn't we wrap it inside a scrollpane (scrollpane invisible) and then elongate it ?